# Get user from multiple auth backend

Tags: python, django, authentication, jwt

Django 2.2, python 3.6

I'm using 2 authentication backends in my application :

```python
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'my_main_app.all_schemas.schema',
    'MIDDLEWARE': [
        'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware',
    ],
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

I can get user info from graphql queries method like :

```python
@login_required
def resolve_curr_user(self, info, parent_id):
    user = info.context.user
```

But I cannot get user from a view :

```python
def curr_user(request):
    request.user # user is None
```

I'm passing the correct headers to the view request :

```js
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', `JWT ${auth_token}`);
const init = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default'
};

const response = await fetch(`/curr_user_route`, init);
```

When authenticating for graphql query, django calls authenticate method from JSONWebTokenBackend class.

**How do I tell django to call the same method for regular views ?**

Comment: How do you create the user session (login) for the "normal" view?

Comment: And you need for sure the `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE`

Comment: @Mathias I do not. Are you suggesting that when user authenticate it must do so against both backend ? (yes, MIDDLEWARE has that string)

Comment: I never used GRAPHENE, but the `AuthenticationMiddleware` is based on the `SessionMiddleware`. Which handles the cookie. If you are using JWT those middlewares are probably not used. Or at least it's not able to create a session using the JWT token. You probably have to implement your own graphene middleware. I hope somebody else can help more.